# Checking if JSON object from promise is null

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I had another similar topic open and it received negative response.  I am facing a legitimate issue here and assure you I have researched this extensively.  I believe my real issue is probably the syntax as I am not a proficient JS coder.  This has been an ongoing struggle for an embarrassing 2 weeks now.  I have the following:

```
fetch('https://example.com/api/submission?data.dateOfService=' + data.dateChanger + '&select=data.endingPettyTotal')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => instance.setValue(data[0].data.endingPettyTotal));
```

I am trying to look at the JSON object and if it's length is zero, set my data.engingPettyTotal to '0'.  If not zero, then set it equal to the JSON object's value, like I have above.

It seems I should be able to accomplish this by checking the response.json().length, something similar to this

```
fetch('https://example.com/api/submission?data.dateOfService=' + data.dateChanger + '&select=data.endingPettyTotal')
    .then(response => {
        if(response.json().length === 0) {
            console.log("empty")
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            console.log("not empty")
            return 
        })
    .then(data => instance.setValue(data[0].Balance));
    }
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to be working either.  Again, assuming I have just messed up syntax or something but then again this async stuff is confusing.  Also assume this could be done with lodash (isEmpty or isNull).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's hard to tell exactly what your parameter's names are... are they "data.dateofService" on the server Side? (assuming below that it is just 'dateOfService')

sending data  via json/FormData have different handling on the PHP side.
an alternate to sending json - is new FormData()... and append('key',"value");
and instead of jsonData attach the formData to the body attribute.

```
const sendData = {
  dateOfService: data.dateChanger,
  select:data.endingPettyTotal
}
const jsonData = JSON.stringify(sendData);
const options = {
  method:"POST",
  body: jsonData
}
fetch('https://example.com/api/submission',options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data=>
    {
    if(data.length == 0) {
      console.error("no data")
    }
    else {
      console.log("not empty")
      instance.setValue(data[0].Balance);
  }
});
```

Comment: dateOfService is actually the value I am taking from the form.  I am using that in the select statement server side (PHP) to query mySQL and then send back the 'Balance' associated with that date.  At any rate, I attempted your above and it works great.  I just added: instance.setValue('0'); for the "no data" if statement.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

`response.json()` returns a promise that resolves with the server sent data

Do your check in the second then()

```
fetch('https://example.com/api/submission?data.dateOfService=' + data.dateChanger + '&select=data.endingPettyTotal')
  .then(response => {
        if(!response.ok){
           return Promise.resolve(0)// or just throw error
        }
       return  response.json())
  }).then(data => 
        // if not array or empty array set as zero
        const val = (Array.isArray(data) && data.length) ? data[0].Balance : 0;
        instance.setValue(val);
   })
```

Answer (score 2):

`response.json()` returns a `Promise` object, try:

```js
fetch('http://your.url')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => instance.setValue(data.length && data[0].Balance));
```

or if you don't want to set value if data.length equals 0:

```js
fetch('http://your.url')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => data.length && instance.setValue(data[0].Balance));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning the a promise that returns the JSON from your first callback function.

Put the check in the second `.then()`.

```
fetch('https://example.com/api/submission?data.dateOfService=' + data.dateChanger + '&select=data.endingPettyTotal')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    if (data.length == 0) {
      console.log("empty");
    } else {
      console.log("not empty");
      instance.setValue(data[0].data.endingPettyTotal));
    }
  });
```